# What is the difference between Primary Key only and Primary Key constraint?

Tags: sql, constraints, primary-key

I am very new to SQL and if my question is silly please forgive my ignorance.

What is the difference between Primary Key only and Primary Key constraint?

Difference between
**This**

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(
   ID   INT              NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID, NAME)
```

and **This**

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(
   ID   INT              NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [Pk_ID_Name] PRIMARY KEY (ID, NAME)
```

Thank you,
Dash

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the second version, you can give a name to your constraint, allowing you to drop it using the name instead of having to name every column of a composite constraint.

Otherwise, they do the same thing.

Comment: Correct.  The reason you would want to give your primary key a name is if you had multiple columns as the primary key.  You could then drop the constraint without naming each individual column in your key.

Answer (score 1):

Well in normal and general English as well, we understand some meaning of constraint that it is a kind of limitation on something.
So primary key constraint means that what are the limitations which are imposed along with making any column as a primary key.

Go through these links:[Primary Key Constraint](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=primary%20key%20contsraing&sugexp=chrome,mod=3&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=primary%20key%20constraint&spell=1&sa=X&ei=zgNwUZXeEYbtrQe-3IDQCQ&ved=0CC4QvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45368065,d.bmk&fp=cb7e50381dccf8de&biw=1366&bih=643)

and [Primary Key](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-primary-key.htm)

Comment: Thank you, I will go through it.:)

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that the primary key column can only be created when you create/add the table or column, not later. The primary key constraint you can add any time later.

Answer (score -2):

You can have only one Primary key per table, but several Constraints

Comment: there can be only one primary key constrains because its a clustered structure, but it can be on multiple columns(with only one clustered key)