# what's the difference between those two sql statements?

Tags: sql, constraints, primary-key, create-table

what's the difference between those two sql statements to set primary key constraints?

first one:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

second one:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (

ID INT NOT NULL ,
constraint pk_Persons primary key (ID)
)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Explicitly named primary key constraint (pk_Persons), or a generated one.

Comment: [Name - db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4a2364aaead5b8ccef0bde37539f217b)

Comment: Or https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=50966edbedf539ccec201ac4cb511275

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Primary Key only and Primary Key constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085724/what-is-the-difference-between-primary-key-only-and-primary-key-constraint)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second version, you can give a name to your constraint and you can make primary key with multiple columns, allowing you to drop it using the name instead of having to name every column of a composite constraint.

This is a duplicate question from [What is the difference between Primary Key only and Primary Key constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085724/what-is-the-difference-between-primary-key-only-and-primary-key-constraint/16085796)

Comment: Duplicate questions should be closed, not answered. [Help]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to actually write NOT NULL because you add a Primary Key constraint.
the Primary Key constraint has 3 rules:

1. Unique
2. Integrity (not null)
3. Relational (every Foreign Key needs to be linked to a correct Primary Key)